# Как получить имя поля структуры в виде строки в Си?

Tags: c, макросы, c99

Есть какая-то структура

```
typedef struct someStruct
{
    uint8_t someField;
    uint8_t anotherField;
}someStruct_t;
```

Нужно получить строку которая будет соответствовать имени поля этой структуры. Например:

```
char field_name [] = SOME_MACRO(someStruct_t.someField); // Нужно получить строку "someField"
```

Возможно ли это реализовать средствами языка С (cтандарт C99)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Си++ можно так:

```
#define FIELD_NAME(s,f) (sizeof(s::f), #f)
```

если не компилируется, то версия для Си:

```
#define FIELD_NAME(s,f) (sizeof(((s*)0)->f), #f)
```

В обоих случаях использовать так:

```
const char *name = FIELD_NAME(someStruct_t, someField);
```

Если написать несуществующее имя поля, то не скомпилируется.

[Код на Си полностью](https://tio.run/##VY7PCsIwDMbvfYrALq1s4lHwDwgqCOrFBxijTV1ha6VNDyo@@@ymoMsp@b7ky08WVym7LjNWNlEhLAMp46b1mo0lS73G6H5DhRoC@SgJgmvxMrTsySBVTIvz8mPsDTZqMZIr66hG/3Vef/clLRjLUrSxCPvD7rgtz5vTjodcC@DBPNBpznmYiJko1lrkkGnBWMqFtjKWiwFAOhsIZF15mNiqRViNsv6@5T9E0TPeIgXenwyTR4rewiwxdt0b)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct someStruct
{
    uint8_t someField;
    uint8_t anotherField;
} someStruct_t;

#define FIELD_NAME(s,f) (sizeof(((s*)0)->f), #f)

int main()
{
  const char *name = FIELD_NAME(someStruct_t, someField);
  puts(name);
  return 0;
}
```

[Код на Си++ полностью](https://tio.run/##VU5LCsIwEN3nFAPdJFLFpdQPCFoQ1I0HKCWd2IBNSjJZqHj2mlZBO6uZ9@Z9ZNtOr1J2XaKNvIUKYeWp0nZWb9gYMtRjjO4tVqjAkwuSwNsGL8PKngzihPi4KD5ErvFWLUdwaSzV6L7M609f0JKxJFprg5Af9sddcd6e9tynSgD3@oFWcZ9lSqSQKMFYdISm1IaLIVpa4wlkXTqYmLJBWI9c/nLSXznRt2sDed5LhsshBWdgHtt13Rs)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct someStruct
{
    uint8_t someField;
    uint8_t anotherField;
} someStruct_t;

#define FIELD_NAME(s,f) (sizeof(s::f), #f)

int main()
{
  const char *name = FIELD_NAME(someStruct_t, someField);
  puts(name);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Так годится](https://ideone.com/o5ATkf)?

```
#define  SOME_MACRO(x) #x
```

Comment: Там получается строка "someStruct_t.someField", но для моей задачи так тоже норм, спасибо)

Comment: Ну, это уже можно потом получить из строки обычными функциями...

Comment: `#define MACRO1(x)  const char x##_name[] = #x;`  Я примерно такую конструкцию использовал для именованых констант. Так тоже можно.

Comment: Такой код скомпилируется даже если имя поля написано неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Конечно.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, тогда толку от него?